# How to get Model data from json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Getting error Key must be quoted. any idea how to get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: That question is not about Dart/Flutter

Comment: Right, this is not a dart question. You should put more generic label here. Anyway, I have answered one possible reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the syntax is giving you the error. When you copy and paste JSON sometimes it gets pasted with - sign. Remove all the - signs in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you don't have "," at the end.

For example -

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2": "value2",
}
```

Above will throw "Key must be quoted" in `quicktype`. Instead do this

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```